# ValidationRegExJavaScript for content item in 2sxc

Tags: 2sxc

Does anyone have any pointer on how this field works?  I'm trying to add a validation so that entered field does not exceed a set amount of characters.

I've tried 
[A-Z]{1,10} and 
/[A-Z]{1,10}/

Both don't work on that field but work on regular input field/javascript validation.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is/was a bug with this, which was recently fixed but not yet released. https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/1447

Should be released in ca. 2 weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Looking forwards to have this fixed as it is very important for our use case.